# PUT request fails with 'Error Code 0' and net::ERR_METHOD_NOT_SUPPORTED (chrome only)

Tags: angular

We have a relatively simple PUT operation, sending some updated data to a .net core API.  CORS is in place, in fact the server logs show a status of 200 for these requests, and the updates are persisted in the database.

> PUT https://myservice/api/QaDataFile/updatedatafields
>   net::ERR_METHOD_NOT_SUPPORTED

The error we get is not instructional `"Error: Error Code 0".`

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being an issue with the web server - new version of .Net Core (2.2) runtime solved a known issue.